# How to have a variable persist from a controller, to a js file, to a rendered partial

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, instance-variables

I'm rendering a partial `viewer` using ajax and jQuery. I want to set a variable within the partial, based on the link that is clicked on.

ERB:

```
<%=link_to "link1", viewer_path(id: Painting.first), remote: true%>
<%=link_to "link2", viewer_path(id: Painting.last), remote: true%>
```

Controller:

```
  def viewer
    @painting = Painting.find_by(:id)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to root_path }
      format.js
    end
  end
```

viewer.js.erb

```
$("#viewer").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'viewer') %>");
```

_viewer.html.erb

```
<%= @painting.name %>
```

But the variable `@painting` isn't set when the partial is rendered so I get an error.

Shouldn't defining the variable in the controller have the value carry though to the partial? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be your problem: when using `Model.find_by`, you need to specify what you are finding by. Try using `Model.find`, which always uses the Model's `:id`, or `Model.find_by_id` or `Model.find_by(id: :id)`.

Make this update in controller#viewer:

```
@painting = Painting.find(:id)
```

You are right though, instance variables (`@painting`) are usable in partials.

Comment: WOOOW I am an idiot. I didn't even consider the problem might be with setting the variable in the first place. Thanks!

Comment: Ya, stack overflow has helped me out in a few situations like that.